Basemap and shapefile with the same EPSG are projected in different positions
I have a question regarding projections on a QGIS project.
When I use Carto Light basemap from the HCMGIS plugin (projected in EPSG:3857), Greece is projected in the same position as a shapefile polygon that I have of the country, which is in EPSG:2100.
Although, when I choose EPSG:2100 for my Carto Light basemap from the HCMGIS plugin (originally in EPSG:3857) Greece is projected in a different position than my shapefile polygon, which is in EPSG:2100.
The project CRS is always set as EPSG:2100.
Is it correct to assume that the shapefile is located in the correct position, although when both CRS' are set in 2100 it doesn't match the basemap?
For better understanding, I am providing an image of the 2nd case, where both the Carto Light and the Greece shapefile are in EPSG:2100. For your convenience I have written on the image the respective information. The orange circle indicates where the shapefile should be positioned.


When you say " I choose EPSG:2100" what did you actually do? don't use the change projection menu as that isn't doing what you think it does.

If the geometries of a layer have the vertices' coordinates referred to e.g. CRS EPSG:3857, then such layer should have the CRS EPSG:3857 assigned, not EPSG:2100.

@IanTurton what I did was to go to the Layers panel, right-click the Carto Light basemap and then click Layer CRS ->Set to EPSG:2100, which is not what I should do if I understand correctly.

@AndreaGiudiceandrea so is it correct to assume that my shapefile is projected in the right position, since it appears on top of Greece when Carto Light basemap's CRS is EPSD:3857 ?
